# How to avoid Out of global stack ERROR when looking for multiple answers?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

After loading the following program using SWI-Prolog and entering queries such as

```
cells([o,x,o,x,o], A).
```

or

```
cells(A, [o,x,o,x,o]).
```

the first result seems to always be correct, but after submitting semicolon to look for more results (and I don't know if there should be additional results in either case), I get a PROLOG SYSTEM ERROR mentioning garbage collection and an Out of global stack error respectively.

```
regla(o,o,o,o).
regla(x,o,o,x).
regla(o,x,o,o).
regla(o,o,x,x).
regla(x,o,x,x).
regla(x,x,o,x).
regla(o,x,x,x).
regla(x,x,x,o).

cells([X | XS], [Y | YS]) :-
    X = o,
    Y = o,
    length([X | XS], LX),
    LX >= 3,
    length([Y | YS], LY),
    LY is LX + 2,
    append([o, o], [X | XS], W),
    append(W, [o, o], Z),
    cellsR(Z, [Y | YS]).

cellsR(_, []).
cellsR([A, B, C | R], [H | T]) :-
    regla(A, B, C, H),
    cellsR([B, C | R], T).
```

I'm assuming that the errors have to do with the way I handle recursion, so maybe someone can have a look at the code and tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You should do a `trace` and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first advice: do not use a tracer. It will not help you a lot. Termination is much too complex than what a step-by-step tracer can show you. Let me give you the reason why your program does not terminate, first:

```
cells([X | XS], [Y | YS]) :-
    X = o,
    Y = o,
    length([X | XS], LX),
    LX >= 3,
    length([Y | YS], LY), false,
    LY is LX + 2,
    append([o, o], [X | XS], W),
    append(W, [o, o], Z),
    cellsR(Z, [Y | YS]).
```

This highlights the part of your program that you will **have** to modify to remove your problem. In other words, as long as you leave that part unchanged, your problem will not go away.

A minimal change is to add a further goal that establishes the relation between the length of those two lists first, before `length/2` is used:

```
cells([X | XS], [Y | YS]) :-
    X = o,
    Y = o,
    list_samelength([_,_|XS], YS),
    length([X | XS], LX),
    LX >= 3,
    length([Y | YS], LY),
    LY is LX + 2,
    append([o, o], [X | XS], W),
    append(W, [o, o], Z),
    cellsR(Z, [Y | YS]).

list_samelength([], []).
list_samelength([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
   list_samelength(Xs, Ys).
```

See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more on this technique.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The solution you suggest seems to do the trick and I suppose it means that this part of the code is now unnecessary `([Y | YS], LY), LY is LX + 2,` since list_samelength already checks that. What I don't understand is why that would happen.

Comment: @luckysori: why would **what** happen?

Comment: the lack of termination in my original program. I can see where I went wrong, but not why.

Comment: @luckysori: That's what the notion of [tag:failure-slice] is about. Above, I have inserted **`false`** into your program. And the remaining program still did not terminate. It was one of the length goals which described infinitely many different lengths. See the tag for failure-slices to get more examples. If you want to master it, you will have to see many of them.